# Sketching/design app for people with OCD

Tags: software-recommendation

I work best when drawing things out, but it’s a great challenge actually doing such.

I have OCD, and am unable to do basic sketches unless they are pixel perfect and symmetrical.

Are there any good design/sketching applications for making perfect, symmetric drawings? I’m not an artist— I don’t need to be able to make complex drawings with beautiful shadings. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For pixel art, have a look at [Aseprite](https://www.aseprite.org/). It has a nice symmetry function with customizable symmetry axes.

Comment: Also, GIMP and Krita both have pixel painting tools, and symmetry painting features.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stated requirements, you may find the software you seek, if you ensure that one of the features is mirroring.

There's two ways that a program manages mirroring. One is dynamic. In this case, you specify a centerline or centerlines and anything you create on one side is duplicated on the other. I'm currently learning a program for 3D modeling in which this is true. It's called Metasequoia, but I would not recommend it for your purposes. I've used it only as an example with which I am aware.

The "static" version of mirroring requires a manual activation of the feature. Again, the center line is created or a grid of the program is used as a reference. Once the drawing is completed, one uses the mirror feature to create a flipped version.

In [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), a free multi-platform vector editor, for example, one creates the primary image, duplicates it, then mirrors that and rejoins it to the original. A few more steps than the dynamic version.

For bitmap editors, [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is also a free multi-purpose program which supports a mirror feature. There's a very [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-1sE2E_flI) showing an example of the steps described above for Inkscape, but specific to GIMP.

There are plenty of tutorial videos on the internet for both programs and for many others, should you discover another to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think mirroring is an essential feature I’m looking for. I’m going to test with it a bit, but I think the best solution is going to be low resolution canvases.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use Krita. it has nice symmetry functions and wonderful curving, line, and freehand smoothing tools.